# discord.py not reaction on embed message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So i'm trying to write a command that reacts when it sees a message with "Diona"

```
async def on_message(message):
channel = message.channel
emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
if "Diona" in message.content: 
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

it's working on users when they send "Diona" but when it's from a bot with embed message it doesn't react on it. How do i make it work?

Comment: You would have to detect the content of an embed then. They work different from a normal message.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the embeds contents by looping through `message.embeds` and looping through all of the fields, getting the title and the description:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    all_data = ""
    if len(message.embeds) > 0:
        for embed in message.embeds: #loop through all embeds in the message
            try: #I use try and except for every, because when the field is empty, TypeError is raised.
                all_data = all_data + embed.description #get embed description
            except TypeError:
                pass
            try:
                all_data = all_data + embed.title #get embed title
            except TypeError:
                pass
            for field in embed.fields: #loop through each field
                try:
                    all_data = all_data + field.value #get value of field
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                try:
                    all_data = all_data + field.name #get name of field
                except TypeError:
                    pass
    if "Diona" in all_data: #test if Diona is in any of the data we got
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    if "Diona" in message.content: 
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

---

**References:**

- [Message.embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)